# WandaVision finale - "Vision" vs "The Vision" in the credits?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

I noticed in the credit listing that the two Vision characters were credited like this:

[image: image of credits quoted below]

> CAST
>
> ...
>
> Vision & The Vision      PAUL BETTANY

Which is which? I can't recall specific attention being paid to the "The" or not during the episode or at other times, but it is such a small detail it could have been easily overlooked.

In fact I'm not sure I can recall anyone ever calling him "The Vision" in the MCU at all (same disclaimer).  [*As noted in comments, "The Vision" was indeed used at various points.*]

In the comics I'm pretty sure his name was indeed "The Vision".

---

*As a guess,* "Vision" may be the predecessor (aka the version Wanda created in the hex) and "The Vision" could be the reanimated body in the sense that Wanda's use of "Vision" is is somewhat affectionate (or even "Vizh"). Whereas the "The" may refer to the actual physical body being the "true" Vision.

On the other hand, Wanda's version certainly seemed more like the authentic character that we all knew.

*Another guess* is that "The Vision" is just a nod to Wanda finally getting called "The Scarlet Witch"?

Comment: He's referred to as The Vision quite a lot in the MCU, for example, a few times in AoU: _"Thor: If he can wield the hammer, he can keep the Mind Stone. It's safe with the Vision and these days, safe is in short supply."_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot ahh yes... great thanks I will have to pay closer attention to that next time!

Comment: Do you want me to try and find some better evidence before you accept the answer? (Not sure there will be any but I can try!)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot ty for the reminder :)  I think your comparison to the credits in previous episodes was fairly authoritative, it would be incredibly sloppy for them to have meant those changes any other way and sloppy is not a word I would associate with the MCU in general!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vision refers to Soul Vision, the one Wanda created when she created the Hex. My only evidence for this is in the credits to previous episodes Paul Bettany is credited as playing Vision. for example, the credits for episode 1, "Filmed Before a Live Studio Audience":

[image: Credits for episode 1, relevant section quoted below]

> CAST
>
> Wanda Maximoff ELIZABETH OLSEN
> Vision PAUL  BETTANY

We see the same in the credits for episode 8, "Previously On". Also note in these credits Agnes is now Agatha Harkness so the character names do update when new information comes to light.

[image: Credits for episode 8, relevant section quoted below]

> CAST
>
> Wanda Maximoff ELIZABETH OLSEN
> Vision PAUL  BETTANY

To be complete the only times in universe "The Vision" is used is when characters are referring to the destroyed body at S.W.O.R.D.. Although Hayward is the only one who does so, I believe, Wanda always calls him Vision or some nickname.

> **Tyler Hayward:** Nine days ago. Maximoff stormed our facility, stole the Vision's body, and resurrected him.
>
> **Jimmy Woo:** But that's in direct violation of Section 36 B of the Sokovia Accords.
>
> **Tyler Hayward:** And the Vision's own living will.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 5, "On a Very Special Episode..."</sub>

The only other character to use "The Vision" in universe during *WandaVision* is White Vision. He doesn't know who he is at that point though and the programming was overseen by Hayward so we can presume some misinformation has been given out to him here.

Lastly, I just want to note that "The Vision" is used to refer to Vision quite a lot in previous films, for example, it is used in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* a few times.

> **Thor:** If he can wield the hammer, he can keep the Mind Stone. It's safe with the Vision and these days, safe is in short supply.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

Therefore, all in universe evidence points to White Vision or the "actual" Vision being called The Vision and Wanda's creation as simply Vision.

---

Just to add a little bit extra though out of universe the team calls Wanda's creation "Soul Vision", as we see below from an interview with Schaeffer. She does also use White Vision but the interviewer used that so she may have simply been using his terminology.

> **One of my favorite scenes in the finale is the Ship of Theseus conversation between the Visions. It's a wonderfully written exchange in the midst of all this punching and blasting. At the end of that conversation, why was it important for you to have Vision give or unlock his memories within White Vision?**
>
> It wasn't about the directive of, where do we leave White Vision? That wasn't the focus. The focus was, how do you resolve the problem of two Visions fighting each other? Where does that end? They'll just be fighting each other until the end of time. It became clear to us that it's got to be a logic battle, right? You've got two Synthezoids with the exact same programming. It's going to come down to logic. The Vision inside the hex, we call him Soul Vision, we wanted Soul Vision to win based on something that was not only incredibly crafty and indicative of his extreme level of intelligence, but also was aligned with his journey, which is one of identity.
>
> So, he's only thought of himself as Vision this whole story. He hasn't been born that long. It's been a couple days. For him to surrender that authentically to his original self, I guess, it just seemed really beautiful and very smart and we loved it. And the idea of the ship of Theseus is actually Megan McDonnell, one of the other writers in the room who's writing *Captain Marvel 2*, she stumbled upon that thought experiment and had to explain it to us, like, eight times. We were still like, "Wait, what is the thing?" [*Laughs*]
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Tonight, 'WandaVision' Creator on Agatha's Master Plan, That Ralph Bohner Reveal and White Vision (Exclusive)](https://www.etonline.com/wandavision-series-finale-interview-jac-schaeffer-161951)</sub>

Comment: "Soul Vision or the "actual" Vision being called ' ....

This completely circumvents the question of which is the true vision.  I don't think you can/should be disambiguating between the two of them by putting "actual" in quotes.

Comment: @ThePopMachine actual meaning the Vision in the body we've seen in previous films. And it doesn't really because the question is not about which is the true Vision, it's about which is called Vision and which is The Vision in the credits.

Comment: Carrot -- Say what you like, but I, for one, don't find the argument that the phrase "actual Vision" necessarily refers to the resurrected body of the Vision from *Endgame* compelling at all.   You're just raising more questions.   Leaving in this text performs the opposite of the goal of disambiguation.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Feel free to ask it as a question of which is the "true/actual" Vision but the whole "logic fight" was devoted to this in the finale. I'm making the distinction because it helps me track which I'm talking about and makes sense to _me_ to call White Vision the "actual" Vision. Quotes being important because is either the true Vision in this case? He's the "actual" in the sense that he has the original Vision's body.

Comment: @Carrot -- Yes, but this intepretation of the word "actual" is exactly the question raised in that episode.   This really isn't the hill to die on, IMO.

Comment: @ThePopMachine you’re right it’s not, and I shall keep it in my answer under the interpretation I’m using for it here.

Comment: @Carrot.   Heh.   I see what you did there.   Obviously, I meant it's not the hill for **you** to die on.    I would like to hear comments from others who stumble upon this.

Comment: FWIW (maybe little) this site refers to "white Vision" as "spectral Vision". https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Spectral_Vision

Comment: @ThePopMachine I thought calling White Vision the "actual" Vision made perfect sense. He has the body; he is the real embodiment of Vision and the other is just Wanda's recreation from her memory.

Comment: @StayOnTarget I saw that, the MCU wiki is usually pretty accurate but as with all fan written things can have mistakes in it. I’m not sure where they got that version of the name from and can’t see a citation. It seems to simply be a fan-made name.